# Get all values of drop down list with multiple options

Tags: jquery

I want to get the value of drop down list with multiple option.I want to get selected and not selected value of drop down list using jquery.Anybody help me?

My code is given below

```
 <select name="select" multiple id="select">
   <option value="aa">aa</option>
   <option value="bb">bb</option>
 </select>
<BR><BR>
<input type="button" value="Print All" onClick="printAll()">
<script>

 function printAll()
  {
    var selectedValues = $("#select").val();
    alert(selectedValues);
  }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need this.check this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/koushikKumar/wF5X6/4/)

**HTML :**

```
   <select name="select" multiple id="select" >
   <option value="aa">aa</option>
   <option value="bb">bb</option>
    <option value="cc">bb</option>
    <option value="dd">bb</option>
 </select>
<input id="printAll"type="button" value="Print All">
```

**jQuery :**

```
 $("#printAll").click(function(){

$('#select option').not(":selected").each(function(){
    alert("unselected :"+$(this).val());
});
});
```

Comment: where is button in these demo?

Comment: want all values,ie ,now got only selected values

Comment: then you should go with jquery map function

Answer (score 0):

To get all not selected:

```
$('#select option:not(:selected)').map(function() { return $(this).val(); });
```

and to get selected:

```
$('#select option:selected').map(function() { return $(this).val(); });;
```

Comment: get value by $('#select option:not(:selected)').val(); is n't it?

Comment: @user3886613: that is just selector. to get the values op can use map function.

Answer (score 0):

To get all the values (both selected and unselected):

```
$('#printAll').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var allValues = $('select[multiple] option').map(function () {
        return this.value;
    }).get();
    console.log(allValues); // ['aa','bb']
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/9PBa5/).

References:

- [`get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/).
- [`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/).
- [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Answer (score 0):

You asked: ***`"I want to get selected and not selected value "`***

A nice way to do it: **[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/hecaje/2/edit)**

```
var arr = [[],[]];
$('#select option').val(function(i,v){
    arr[+this.selected].push(v);
});
alert( "Unselected: "+ arr[0] +"\n Selected: "+ arr[1] );
```